# 504 gateway timeout - ELB, Nginx, Gunicorn

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, gunicorn

Helllo guys.
I am unable to download long-running reports. The site is under ELB, nginx and gunicorn as a backend server. In nginx I configured following settings:

> proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
> proxy_send_timeout 600s;
> proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
> send_timeout 600s;
> fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;
> fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
> fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

In ELB I configured Idle timeout as 600 seconds.

I started Gunicorn with timeout 600 seconds.

Any ideas why I am getting 504 Gateway timeout error.

Here is a piece of log from ELB:

> h2 2020-08-31T18:30:38.619550Z app/ELBNAME/ef76928f240170a7 ip:58854 172.30.1.7:80 0.000 60.013 0.000 504 504 1906 1128 "POST domain/admin/report/stripe-transaction-report HTTP/2.0" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36" ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1::targetgroup/ELBNAME/9405a9cc2732dfb2 "Root=1-" "domain" "session-reused" 0 2020-08-31T18:29:38.605000Z "forward" "-" "-" "172.30.1.7:80" "504" "-" "-"

Not sure how to interpret it...

Comment: i see nothing about timeout in nginx logs and gunicorn logs (before I bumped up timeout setting for gunicorn I saw something like: worker is killed if there's a timeout or something like this and it starts immediately new worker). It seems like it's ELB.... But I am not sure.

Comment: Please edit your question to add all additional information, properly formatted. Logs are really difficult to read in comments.

Comment: thanks for advice, done.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, edited question with a piece from log

Comment: It looks like this timed out after 60 seconds, not 600. You may want to check your ELB configuration again.

Comment: I checked out few times. That's strange, I put there 600. It's in seconds.... Hm. what am I missing ?